# Sum a staggered array "columns" in this way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have the following array

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([
     [[1, 2,   3,   4], [0,   1], [2,   3,   4,  5]],
     [[1, 2,   3], [4], [0,   1], [2,   0], [0,  0]],
     [[2, 2], [3,   4,   0], [1,   1,   0,   0], [0]],
     [[6, 3,   3,   4,   0], [4,   2,   3,   4,  5]],
     [[1, 2,   3,   2], [0,   1,   2], [3,   4,  5]]])
```

As you can see, it's a staggered  array. What I want to do is to sum the elements in a way so that the output is:

```
     [11, 11, 15, 18, 0, 8, 9, 9, 12, 15]
```

I want to sum the elements in the "columns" of the matrix, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You cant expect someone else to solve your assignment

Comment: No, that is *not* a multidimensional array. Check `matrix.shape`, you'll get `(5,)`. Numpy does not support staggered arrays, it has *true multidimensional arrays*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're rigth, edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by juanpa.arrivillaga in the comments, you don't have a multi-dimensional array, you have a 1-D array of lists of lists. You need to flatten the inner lists first :

```
>>> np.array([[z for y in x for z in y] for x in matrix])
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

It should be much easier to solve your problem now. This matrix has a shape of `(5,10)`, and supports [`T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) for transposition and [`np.sum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) for summing rows or columns.

You didn't write any code, so I won't solve the problem completely, but with this matrix, you're one step away from:

```
array([11, 11, 15, 18,  0,  8,  9,  9, 12, 15])
```

Comment: *Or* if we are feeling crazy: `np.array(list(map(sum,(zip(*map(itertools.chain.from_iterable, matrix))))))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Ahah, nice! Your code is broken by SO comments though, with added `<200c><200b>` chars in the middle.